# Using Hibernate last versions in Webpshere 7

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, websphere-7

WebSphere 7 support only JEE5, not 6. So it doesn't support JPA2 specification (I understand that Hibernate implements JPA2 specification). But how does Hibernate work with Tomcat and Jetty (they're only servlet containers, not app servers, and they don't support EE and JPA2)? If Hibernate can work with Tomcat, why can't the latest version work with WAS 7?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the IBM WebSphere Application Server V7 Feature Pack for OSGi Applications and Java Persistence API 2.0

Comment: Yes you can just download it from IBM. Are you using this with RAD?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to put all JPA api JARs you need into the WAR or EAR and set the class loader to PARENT_LAST. We've done that on a number of occasions when WebSphere has been behind the curve.

Comment: As a warning, this will prevent container-managed JPA from working.  In other words, injection and refs won't work, and you'll need to use application-managed artifacts only.

Comment: Or you use @Configurable and Spring to do it anyways.

Comment: Yes, that might alleviate some of the developer concerns.  However, container-managed allows tighter integration for performance, logging, etc.